# For all $x$ close to $c$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

What is the precise mathematical meaning of the phrase "for all $x$ close to $c$"? Does it mean that for all $x$ that satisfy the inequality $|x-c|<\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number? This phrase is used very often.

Comment: You've already solved your question.

Comment: Yes, it means for all values within a neighborhood of a particular value. If you mention in what area you saw this we can be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $c$ that the statement in question is valid for each $x\in U$, which is very close to what you have written down. To make your statement formally correct you could reformulate it as 'there exists $\varepsilon>0$  such that the statement in question is true for $|x-c|<\varepsilon$'.

Answer (score 1):

Simply?  Yes,  you're more or less correct (not as formal as you could be, but that's a bit beside the point) Depending on the context epsilon could be arbitrarily small,  perhaps infinitesimal,  or could be quite large.  Nevertheless,  you are correct in general.